# How to convert decimal string in python to a number?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - Parse String to Float or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/python-parse-string-to-float-or-int)

How can I convert '1.03' (string) to a number in Python, preferably a decimal ?

Answer (score 29):

Just use `float()`

```
>>> float('1.03')
1.03
```

If you need an actual `Decimal` type, use the [`decimal` module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html):

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> Decimal('1.03')
Decimal('1.03')
```

In general, using floats will be easier for you, but you pay for that with the inexact precision that comes with floats.

Comment: Of course, a `float` isn't a `decimal` and will have trouble with some decimal numbers.

Answer (score 7):

`float`, `int`, and `decimal` can automatically convert valid strings.

For example:

```
float('1.03')
```

Comment: int('1.03') is going fail, though.  You'll need something like int(float('1.03')) for that.