# How to convert Decimal() to a number in Python?

Tags: python

I have a JSON output that is `Decimal('142.68500203')`.

I can use str() to get a string which is `"142.68500203"`. But I want to get a number output which is `142.68500203`.

How to make the conversion in Python?

Comment: what is that `Decimal`? have you tried call float?

Comment: `float(…)` – Of course `str()` gives you a string, that’s the whole point. If you want a different type, you need to use that type’s converter.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to convert it? The reason that the JSON output is a Decimal is that you don't lose any precision that way. A float might not be able to store the number exactly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert decimal string in python to a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794779/how-to-convert-decimal-string-in-python-to-a-number)

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean by "number", it could be argued that `Decimal` is a number class.  If you mean into an object of `float` class then:

```
from decimal import Decimal

x = Decimal('142.68500203')

y = float(x)

print x, y
```

Gives:

```
142.68500203 142.68500203
```

But beware!  There are good reasons for using `Decimal`, read [the Decimal documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) before deciding you want `float`.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy:

```
float("142.68500203")
```

Comment: Converting a string to a float was not asked for.